# check if object is a textbox - javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, object, textbox

I understand that we can use (javascript)

```
if (typeof textbox === "object") { }
```

but are there methods which will allow me to ensure that the object is a textbox?

Comment: What do you mean `textbox`? `textarea`, `input`...?

Answer (score 45):

```
var isInputText = obj instanceof HTMLInputElement && obj.type == 'text';
```

Comment: A word of warning: if your app is one of those rare ones that use multiple windows with cross-window DOM inspection (or similar), `window.HTMLInputElement === otherWindow.HTMLInputElement` will be false, thus the `instanceof` operator may also unexpectedly return false. Applies to iframes and popup windows as well. In those cases, checking `tagName` can work, as other answers already mentioned.

Answer (score 27):

As of **2016**, use this:

```js
function isTextBox(element) {
    var tagName = element.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if (tagName === 'textarea') return true;
    if (tagName !== 'input') return false;
    var type = element.getAttribute('type').toLowerCase(),
        // if any of these input types is not supported by a browser, it will behave as input type text.
        inputTypes = ['text', 'password', 'number', 'email', 'tel', 'url', 'search', 'date', 'datetime', 'datetime-local', 'time', 'month', 'week']
    return inputTypes.indexOf(type) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: inputTypes should also include `'tel'` 

Comment: Thanks @ShaunLeBron. Added.

Comment: Also make sure this is true: `element.isContentEditable`

Comment: `element.isContentEditable` can be false for editable inputs, so don't rely on that being true. the `readonly` attribute may also be relevant.

Comment: I was seeing an error `inputTypes.contains is not a function` around code that looks like a modified version of this including the exact same comment. Can't find the code on GitHub or anywhere on my machine. Finally discovered it was from the RoboForm password manager. There are also [multiple repositories on Github](https://github.com/search?q=%22//+if+any+of+these+input+types+is+not+supported+by+a+browser,+it+will+behave+as+input+type+text.%22&type=code) with this exact comment. All the versions are in different levels of modification... This is crazy

Answer (score 12):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
if(textbox.tagName && textbox.tagName.toLowerCase() == "textarea") {
    alert('this is a textarea');
}
```

If you need to know if it's a text input, you can do this:

```
if(textbox.tagName && textbox.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input" && textbox.type.toLowerCase() == "text") {
    alert('this is a text input');
}
```

Comment: @Sime: sometimes, it depends on the browser and whether it's in HTML or XHTML. I'll update my answer to make sure it works.

Comment: @Sime: http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/tagName. Opera returns it how it was typed, HTML is uppercase, XHTML is preserved.

Comment: @Jordan Yes: *"In HTML this is returned in all uppercase..."*

Comment: @Sime, right, so if the document is XHTML, it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Either way I edited my answer so that it takes all of that into account, regardless of doctype and browser.

Comment: @Jordan (1) XHTML documents have the "text/html" mime-type, so browsers treat them as HTML documents, not XML documents. (2) This Opera-thing is only for namespaced elements (custom element types).

Comment: @Šime Vidas - If you deliver your XHTML as "application/xhtml+xml" it is supposed to be treated differently, noting that not all browsers actually support that. (Though in my view XHTML is a waste of time if you're just going to deliver it as "text/html".)

Comment: @nnn Yes, but in IRL XHTML documents delivered as "application/xhtml-xml" don't exist (at least I haven't heard of any prominent web-server doing it), since IE doesn't have a XML parser. All web-pages on the web are "text/html", ergo, `tagName` will always be uppercase.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a text input you're looking for:

```
if (textbox.tagName == "input" && textbox.getAttribute("type") == "text") {
   // it's a text input
}
```

If you're looking for a textarea

```
if (textbox.tagName == "textarea") {
  // it's a textarea
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(textbox instanceof HTMLInputElement && textbox.getAttribute("type") == "text") {
    alert("I'm an input text element");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps you would want to get a reference to an element, and then check for the return value of .type  i.e.

```
var element = document.getElementById('element_in_question');
if(element.type == "textarea"){
  console.log('I must be textarea');
}
```

Comment: this is completely wrong answer. element.type will give undefined no matter what type of element.

Comment: Sorry, but `evt.target.type` gives me "text".